# ASP.NET WebApi Odata error 404

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am new to OData.

Thus, I'm following this tutorial very closely. (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/getting-started-with-odata-in-web-api/create-a-read-only-odata-endpoint)

However, in the 2nd part of the tutorial (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/getting-started-with-odata-in-web-api/explore-the-odata-endpoint), when I try to browse `http://localhost:52868/odata/products.svc` in fiddler, or in browser, I get a 404 error.

The OData package I installed is this http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.odata

The package was just released on the 18th, I'm not sure if anything has changed since the tutorial was posted almost a month ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial is a bit off here. If you defined your route like this:

```
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);
```

Then you need to browse to:

```
http://localhost:52868/odata
```

to view the service document. Similarly, you can go to:

```
http://localhost:52868/odata/$metadata
```

to view the metadata document, and

```
http://localhost:52868/odata/Products
```

to get the Products entity set in OData.

Comment: Yeah, it's brand new. I'll do what I can to get it fixed. The text is technically correct. It's just the images that are rather misleading.